# SqlException: Incorrect syntax near @VariableName in asp.net mvc core

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to insert a data (actually a video) to database **using Stored Procedure in MS SQL in ASP.NET MVC core**

I have this code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string title, IFormFile file, string filesize ,string filePath )
    {
        var Title= new SqlParameter("@Title", title);
        var UploadType = new SqlParameter("@UploadType", file.ToString());
        var FileSize = new SqlParameter("@FileSize", filesize);
        var FilePath = new SqlParameter("@FilePath", filePath);


        var insertVideo = _context.Lectures.FromSql("usp_AddNewVideoFile (@Title,@UploadType, @FileSize, @FilePath) ",parameters:new[] {Title,FileSize,FilePath,UploadType }).ToList();
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("Source",insertVideo);
    }
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[usp_AddNewVideoFile]

@Title nvarchar(50),  
@UploadType nvarchar(50),
@FileSize int = null,  
@FilePath nvarchar(MAX)

as  
begin  

insert into Lectures(Name,FileSize,FilePath,UploadType)   
values (@Title,@FileSize,@FilePath,@UploadType)   

end
```

Getting an error saying:

> SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '@Title'.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test(string title, IFormFile file, int filesize, string filePath)
{
    var Title = new SqlParameter("@Title", title);
    var UploadType = new SqlParameter("@UploadType", file.ToString());
    var FileSize = new SqlParameter("@FileSize", filesize);
    var FilePath = new SqlParameter("@FilePath", filePath);

    //change this...    
    var insertVideo = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("usp_AddNewVideoFile @Title,@UploadType,@FileSize, @FilePath", parameters: new[] { Title, UploadType, FileSize, FilePath });

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction("Source", insertVideo);
}
```

Comment: Your change did show some effect. Solved my greatest error. Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this please:

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string title, IFormFile file, string filesize ,string filePath )
    {
        var Title= new SqlParameter("@Title", title);
        var UploadType = new SqlParameter("@UploadType", file.ToString());
        var FileSize = new SqlParameter("@FileSize", filesize);
        var FilePath = new SqlParameter("@FilePath", filePath);


        var insertVideo = _context.Lectures.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE usp_AddNewVideoFile @Title, @FilePath, @FilePath, @UploadType", parameters:new[] {Title,FileSize,FilePath,UploadType }).ToList();
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("Source",insertVideo);
    }
```

Comment: Now it should be ok. Please check it.

Comment: But what you just wrote here is something that I wrote. I don't see any difference? It's just the bracket that you have removed. Anyway, let me check.

Comment: Brackets. Please check this [link](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-execute-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-core/)

Comment: now it is giving me different error saying: 'ArgumentException: No mapping exists from object type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile to a known managed provider native type'

Comment: Ok I changed to `FromSqlRaw` and added `execute`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212851/discussion-between-noobprogrammer-and-krzysztof-madej).

Comment: I executed, I am now getting this error: "The required column 'VideoId' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.". I don't understand. VideoId is set to auto-increment and is the Primary Key then why is it expecting here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```sql
usp_AddNewVideoFile (@Title,@UploadType, @FileSize, @FilePath)
```

That's not quite how you call an SP; the *ideal* way would be to specify the command type as `CommandType.StoredProcedure`, and just specify `"usp_AddNewVideoFile"` as the `CommandText`. If that isn't possible due to `FromSql`, then:

```sql
EXEC usp_AddNewVideoFile @Title,@UploadType, @FileSize, @FilePath;
```

Note, however, that if this is the EF `FromSql`, then using it for an insert command probably isn't ideal; you're really looking for an "execute non query" API.